# Number line jumping algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Can you recommend an algorithm for the following problem? If you have any suggestion for simplifying the problem I am open to it.

There is a number line going from $0$ to $x$. There are $r$ rewards and $o$ obstacles placed on the line. Items can only be placed on whole numbers. There is an animal at point 0 which can jump forward and backwards. There is an array of jump lengths for the animal, for example animal A can jump either 1,2 or 5 in any direction.

Given this information, I need an algorithm that decides if the level can be solved (that is, if all rewards can be collected without landing on any of the obstacles) and what is the least amount of jumps it takes to solve it. (We don't care about the length of the jumps.)

Comment: This has the flavor of the traveling salesman problem. In more detail, you can easily compute the distance (as measured in number of jumps) between any two interest points in your line (these are the origin and the rewards), and then you want to find the optimal order on the rewards which minimizes the total distance it takes to get from the origin to all of them in that order.

Comment: If you just want to know whether the level can be solved, this is easier – you just need to check that the graph comprising of the origin and all rewards is connected.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Have you tried dynamic programming?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  Can you credit the original source where you encountered this task?